# angularJs JSONP - error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, jsonp

I'm trying to make a basic jsonp request with angularjs but I keep getting error 404. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('carApp', []);


    app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'CarFactory', function ($scope, CarFactory) {
        CarFactory.then(function () {
            console.log("ok");
        }, function () {

        });
    }]);

    app.factory('CarFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        // I hide the domain as I'm not allowed to share this
        var url = "http://*mydomain*/cars.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        return $http.jsonp(url).
                success(function (data) {
                    console.log("ok - store")    
                    //it never gets here                
                }).
                error(function (error) {
                    console.log("error - store")   
                    //im getting this error all the time  

                })         
    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

1) Cors are not enabled on the server
2) not sure if jsonp is enabled server side

Do I have any other options?

Comment: open the jsonp url in browser can see if it serves jsonp.. other options are use YQL or a proxy on your server

Comment: It shows up a JSON rather than JSONP (I'd expect to see a JSON within function/var but I just see a plain JSON intead)

Comment: not jsonp then if you used callback param in url

Comment: not sure If I understand you - I added ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK at the end of url in the browser and nothing has changed

Comment: then api isn't set up for jsonp ...have to use a proxy